# Riak setup and LB?

Tags: load-balancing, database, nosql, riak

Quick question about setting up riak cluster.

Do I need load balancer in front of the cluster ?

The cluster will have 3 nodes with N =3, so successful write must have the data in 3 nodes.

Any suggestion on how to setup this environment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended best practice mode of production Riak operation suggests placing Riak behind a load balancing or proxy solution, either hardware or software based, and never exposing Riak directly to public network interfaces.

Riak users have reported success in using Riak with a variety of load balancing and proxy solutions. Common solutions include proprietary hardware based load balancers, cloud based load balancing options, such as Amazon's Elastic Load Balancer, and open source software based projects like HAProxy and Nginx.